# How can I use AngularJS 1 to create table rows with the attributes of an array of objects?

Tags: angularjs, html-table

So far I've only found examples that put the objects in the rows [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35919774/how-display-array-of-objects-in-table-using-angularjs-dynamically)[(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127834/how-can-i-iterate-over-the-keys-value-in-ng-repeat-in-angular)[(3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34412710/create-a-table-from-scope-object-values), but I need to put the objects in the columns and their attributes in the rows.

Example of JSON:

```
[
  {
    name: 'peanut butter',
    price: 0.99
  }
  {
    name: 'strawberry jelly',
    price: 0.99
  }
  {
    name: 'white bread',
    price: 2.99
  }
]
```

Example of desired table:

[image: table that shows a row for name and a row for price, with peanut butter, strawberry jelly and white bread and their prices in the columns]

Comment: I guess you need to first check for all available attributes you got, and create a list based of this. Then do an ng-repeat on this list for the table-rows. Inside this do a second ng-repeat for the objects in the columns. **<tr ng-repeat="attr in attributes"><td>{{attr.name}}</td><td ng-repeat="obj in objList"></td></tr>**  - if you don't need a dynamic version, do like Konrad suggested in his answer, with a hardcoded list of rows.

Comment: I'll try that when I need to build a reusable directive. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this.

Angular template:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th ng-repeat="item in yourList">{{ item.name }}</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td ng-repeat="item in yourList">{{ item.price }}</td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```